# How to pass a javascript-generated DOM element to react render function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, render

I am a newbie to react. I'm trying to create a component named StationBrowserForHome (TSX). In the render() function, I want to render a DOM element looks like this:

```
<div class = "big-group">
 <div class = "small-group>
   <div class="item"></item>
   <div class="item"></item>
   ...
   <div class="item"></item>
 </div>
 <div class = "small-group>
   <div class="item"></item>
   <div class="item"></item>
   ...
   <div class="item"></item>
 </div>
 ...
</div>
```

So I tried to create that DOM tree in componentWillMount(), set it to state variable "divItems", and in render(), I retrieve it

```
export class StationBrowserForHome extends Component <{}, any> {
    componentWillMount (){
        var divItems = document.createElement("div");
        var divSeven = document.createElement("div");

        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            var singleItem = document.createElement('<div className="station-item"><div className="row"><StationBrowserItemInfo/></div><div className="row station-name">Station {i}</div></div>');
            divSeven.appendChild(singleItem);
            console.log("singleItem: "+singleItem);
            console.log("divSeven: "+divSeven);

        }
        divItems.appendChild(divSeven);
        this.setState({divItems:divItems});
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid text-center browser">
                <div className="cover-div">
                    <ArrowButton/>
                    <div className="text-center list-station" id="station-browser">
                        { this.state.divItems }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
  }
}
```

And I got this error message:

> VM19339 invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a
>   React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

React is great because you can break things down into reusable components. This code kind of goes against the whole meanings of react.

Everything in componentWillMount should be inside a component with props `numberOfItems` for example and then based on that you will render what it seems to me would be a station item.

```
export class StationList extends React.Component<{stations: IStation[]}, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
       <div className='stations'>
         {this.getStationItems}
       </div>
    );
  }

  private getStationItems() {
     const itemsDiv = this.props.stations.map((station, index) => {
       return (
          <div className='station'>
            //........
            // other stuff here
          </div>
       )
     });
     return itemsDiv;

  }
}
```

Then back in the `StationBrowserForHome` component we just:

```
    const stations: IStation[] = [
       {
          id: 'station1',
          purpose: 'purpose1'
       },
       {
          id: 'station2',
          purpose: 'purpose2'
       }
    ];

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid text-center browser">
            <div className="cover-div">
                <ArrowButton/>
                <div className="text-center list-station" id="station-browser">

                    <StationList stations={stations} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

The code above is just a generic template not in front of an IDE but thats the basic gist.

Answer (score 0):

why you use this way , you can easily create an element with JSX like this

```
componentWillMount() {
  let ele = <div> </div>;
  }
```

and if you want loop with element or any work on that you can use map function (method for looping in javascript like foreach) like this

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.state.count.map( (e) => ( ... ) )
  }
```

in above example e parameter , refer on your object for example

```
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       data:[ 
        {
           id:1,
           name:'hamid'
         },
         {
           id:2,
           name:'mat'
         },
         {
           id:3,
           name:'sara'
         }

        ]    
       }

    this.state.data.map( (item) => (

        <li key={item.id} > {item.name} </li>       

     ));
```

you have this in your DOM

```
   <li>hamid</li>
   <li>mat</li>
   <li>sara</li>
```

and you must set key attribute in top level root element inside map function , and this must be uniq for each item

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create on **functional component** and passed the required data for its rendering.

```
const MyComp = ({counter}) => {
    return (
      <div>{(" ".repeat(7).split("")).map((value, index) => (
          <div class="big-group">
            <div class="small-group">{index+1}</div> //for example
          </div>
        ))
}</div>
    );
  }
```

Inside the render, passed the state data to it.data

```
 render(){
    return(<div>

    ....
    <MyComp counter = {7} />
    </div>);
  }
```

Comment: Yeh could use functional component for something simple like this instead. Though that .map won't work ;)